Error trying to connect Oracle forms 6i with oracle DB 11.2.0.4.0
I've installed Oracle DB v11.2.0.4.0 on my machine, configured the listener.ora and the tnsnames.ora too.
The problem begins when i try to connect Oracle Forms Builder 6i with the database, because it closes suddenly.
In the sqlnet.log file. I've got this:
Fatal NI connect error 12203, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)(PROGRAM=oracle80)(ARGV0=oracle80ORCL)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))')))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\Orant\BIN\ifrun60.EXE)(HOST=DEV1)(USER=resid))))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 8.0.6.0.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 8.0.6.0.0 - Production
  Time: 10-SEP-24 09:33:26
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    nr err code: 12203
    TNS-12203: TNS:unable to connect to destination
    ns main err code: 12560
    TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 530
    TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0

This is the LSNRCTL status says:
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DEV1)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                10-SEP-2024 09:32:00
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 2 sec
Trace Level               off

Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\app\resid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         D:\app\resid\diag\tnslsnr\DEV1\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DEV1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

And this is my Listener.ora files config:
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\resid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\resid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\resid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\resid\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DEV1)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\resid

Tnsnames.ora
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DEV1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )

I've searching for a solution but nothing that i found it worked. I'll appreciate your responses.

You're using almost 20 year old technology. Is your operating system also 20 years old? That software isn't supported by Oracle and likely won't run reliably (if at all) or securely on any modern operating system version. Why are you using it?
